# Reducing data size to make a boxplot

Tags: r, perl, statistics

I am working with large arrays from data files using perl, and then placing them into R to make boxplots.  This works very well with small datasets.  However, I want to enter in large data sets to present to my colleagues.
I would like a way to reduce the number of data points, and keep the boxplot looking the same (same max, min, quartiles, etc.) because perl eats up memory fast (each dataset is about 5GB of RAM) and so does R.  I'm sure there is a 10MB solution for what is currently a 120GB problem.

Is there a way to reduce the data size so it will look the same in the boxplot *before* I put it into R?  I feel stupid, because what I have done so far only works for trivially small data sets like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings; use Cwd 'getcwd';
my $TOP_DIRECTORY = getcwd();
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {#kill the program if there are any warnings
    my $message = shift;
    my $fail_filename = "$TOP_DIRECTORY/$0.FAIL";
    open my $fh, '>', $fail_filename or die "Can't write $fail_filename: $!";
    printf $fh ("$message @ %s\n", getcwd());
    close $fh;
    die "$message\n";
};#http://perlmaven.com/how-to-capture-and-save-warnings-in-perl

sub reduce_size {#returns min, lower quartile, median, upper quartile, and max if > 5 elements
# R is not able to handle large arrays as Perl is.  This subroutine reduces the work on R, which can't handle the size
#this does NOT work for means
    my $x = shift;
#   if (scalar @{ $x } < 6) {
#       return @{ $x };
#   }
    my @sorted = sort {$a <=> $b} @{ $x };
    my $n = scalar @{ $x };
    my @return = $sorted[0];#minimum
    if (($n % 2) == 0) {
        $return[1] = $sorted[$n/4 ] ;
        $return[2] = ($sorted[$n/2 - 1] + $sorted[$n/2])/2;
        $return[3] = $sorted[3*$n/4 ] ;
    } else {
        my $i = sprintf("%.0f", $n/4);
        $return[1] = ($sorted[ $i - 1] + $sorted[$i])/2;
        $return[2] = $sorted[$n/2];
        $i = sprintf("%.0f", 3*$n/4);
        $return[3] = ($sorted[$i-1] + $sorted[$i])/2;
    }
    push @return, $sorted[-1];#maximum
    return @return;
}

my @x = qw(-0.82312297 -0.08696213  2.23698132  0.20834949  0.73162884  0.22891093 1.04418464 -0.67952858  0.08111757);

my @y = reduce_size(\@x);

print join (',', @y) . "\n";
```

Comment: Do you really need boxplots for the summaries, or could you instead just show a table of statistics, such as those in your `reduce_size` sub? You could also modify it to produce the same values (ie, whiskers, hinges) returned by `boxplot.stats()` in R, and then list them in a table or create a custom plot based on those.

Comment: Why are you returning a array "return @return". You should be returning array reference. "return \@return"

Comment: @MarkS indeed, the solution to this problem is to simply translate R's `fivenum` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to translate R's `fivenum` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings; use Cwd 'getcwd'; use feature 'say';
my $TOP_DIRECTORY = getcwd();
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {#kill the program if there are any warnings
    my $message = shift;
    my $fail_filename = "$TOP_DIRECTORY/$0.FAIL";
    open my $fh, '>', $fail_filename or die "Can't write $fail_filename: $!";
    printf $fh ("$message @ %s\n", getcwd());
    close $fh;
    die "$message\n";
};#http://perlmaven.com/how-to-capture-and-save-warnings-in-perl

use POSIX qw(ceil floor);

sub fivenum {
    my $array = shift;
    my @x = sort {$a <=> $b} @{ $array };
    printf("There are %u elements.\n", scalar @{ $array });
    my $n = scalar @{ $array };
    if ($n == 0) {
        print "no values were entered into fivenum.\n";
        die;
    }
    my $n4 = floor(($n+3)/2)/2;
    my @d = (1, $n4, ($n +1)/2, $n+1-$n4, $n);#d <- c(1, n4, (n + 1)/2, n + 1 - n4, n)
    my (@floor_d, @ceiling_d);
    foreach my $d (0..4) {
          $floor_d[$d] = floor($d[$d]);
        $ceiling_d[$d] =  ceil($d[$d]);
    }
    my @sum_array;
    foreach my $e (0..4) {
        if (not defined $floor_d[$e]) {
            say "\$floor_d[$e] isn't defined.";
            die;
        }
        if (not defined $ceiling_d[$e]) {
            say "\$ceiling_d[$e] isn't defined.";
            die;
        }
        if (!defined $x[$floor_d[$e]-1]) {
            say "\$x[$floor_d[$e-1]-1] isn't defined.";
            die;
        }
        if (!defined $x[$ceiling_d[$e]-1]) {
            say "\$x[$ceiling_d[$e]-1] isn't defined.";
            die;
        }
        printf("sum_array has %u elements.\n", scalar @sum_array);
        push @sum_array, (0.5 * ($x[$floor_d[$e]-1] + $x[$ceiling_d[$e]-1]));
    }
    return @sum_array;
}

my @x = qw(0.14082834  0.09748790  1.73131507  0.87636009 -1.95059594  0.73438555
-0.03035726  1.46675970 -0.74621349 -0.72588772  0.63905160  0.61501527
 -0.98983780 -1.00447874 -0.62759469  0.66206163  1.04312009 -0.10305385
  0.75775634  0.32566578);

my @y = fivenum(\@x);

say join (',', @y);
```